# Azure HDInsight cluster with Hbase + pheonix using Local Index

Tags: azure, hbase, azure-hdinsight

We have an HDInsight cluster running HBase (Ambari)

1. We have created a table using Pheonix

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Results (Col1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,Col1
>   INTEGER NOT NULL ,Col3 INTEGER NOT NULL,**Destination** VARCHAR(255)
>   NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (Col1,Col2,Col3) )
>   IMMUTABLE_ROWS=true

2. We have filled some data into this table (using some java code)
3. Later, we decided we want to create a local index on the **destination** column as follows

> CREATE LOCAL INDEX DESTINATION_IDX ON RESULTS (**destination**) ASYNC

4. We have run the index tool to fill the index as follows

> hbase org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.index.IndexTool  --data-table
>   RESULTS --index-table DESTINATION_IDX  --output-path
>   DESTINATION_IDX_HFILES

5. When we run queries and filter using the **destination** columns everything is ok. For example

> select /*+ NO_CACHE, SKIP_SCAN */ COL1,COL2,COL3,DESTINATION from
>   Results where COL1='data' **DESTINATION**='some value' ;

6. But, if we do not use the DESTINATION in the where query, then we will get a NullPointerException in BaseResultIterators.class

> (from phoenix-core-4.7.0-HBase-1.1.jar)

7. This exception is thrown only when we use the new local index. If we query ignoring the index like this

> select /*+ NO_CACHE, SKIP_SCAN ,**NO_INDEX** */ COL1,COL2,COL3,DESTINATION from
>   Results where COL1='data' **DESTINATION**='some value' ;

we will not get the exception

Showing some relevant code from the area where we get the exception

```
...
catch (StaleRegionBoundaryCacheException e2) {
// Catch only to try to recover from region boundary cache being out of date
if (!clearedCache) { // Clear cache once so that we rejigger job based on new boundaries
                                services.clearTableRegionCache(physicalTableName);

context.getOverallQueryMetrics().cacheRefreshedDueToSplits();
}
// Resubmit just this portion of work again
Scan oldScan = scanPair.getFirst();
byte[] startKey = oldScan.getAttribute(SCAN_ACTUAL_START_ROW);
byte[] endKey = oldScan.getStopRow();

====================Note the isLocalIndex is true ==================
if (isLocalIndex) {
     endKey = oldScan.getAttribute(EXPECTED_UPPER_REGION_KEY);

    //endKey is null for some reason in this point and the next function 
    //will fail inside it with NPE

}

List<List<Scan>> newNestedScans = this.getParallelScans(startKey, endKey);
```

8. We must use this version of the Jar since we run inside Azure HDInsight
   and we can not select a newer jar version
9. Any ideas how to solve this?
   What does "recover from region boundary cache being out of date" mean? it seems to be related to the problem

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the version that azure HDInsight has for phoenix core (phoenix-core-4.7.0.2.6.5.3004-13.jar) has the bug but if i use a bit newer version (phoenix-core-4.7.0.2.6.5.8-2.jar, from http://nexus-private.hortonworks.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/hwxreleases/org/apache/phoenix/phoenix-core/4.7.0.2.6.5.8-2/) we do not see the bug any more

note that it is not possible to take a much newer version like 4.8.0 since in this case the server will throw a version mismatch error